# eslint error in React app persists after attempts to disable

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app, eslint

I'm developing a Chrome extension using `create-react-app`. I've gotten my extension to load properly and communicate with the extension background. To get this working I had to flag the chrome global message for `eslint`.

```
// This works perfectly

/* global chrome */

let port = chrome.runtime.connect('extensionID',
  {name: "bgconnect"})

// Background responses are handled here
port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  console.log('Got message from background',msg)
  if (msg.error) {
    this.setState({error: msg.error})
  } 
})
```

When I try to add an additional chrome function using `chrome.local.storage`, however, I get

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['myKey'], result => {
  if (result.myKey) {
    this.setState({signedIn: true})
  }
})
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Here's what I've tried:

### Verify manifest.js

```
...
"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>",
  "tabs",
  "storage"
 ] 
...
```

### eslint 1

```
/* global chrome */
chrome.storage.local.get(['myKey'], result => {
  if (result.myKey) {
    this.setState({signedIn: true})
  }
})
```

### eslint 2

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
chrome.storage.local.get(['myKey'], result => {
  if (result.myKey) {
    this.setState({signedIn: true})
  }
})
/* eslint-enable no-undef */
```

### eslint 3

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
chrome.storage.local.get(['myKey'], result => {
  if (result.myKey) {
    this.setState({signedIn: true})
  }
})
```

### package.json

```
...

"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app",
  "globals": {
    "chrome": true
  }
},
...
```

I still get the same error despite making these changes.

One other weird thing is in console (Windows Powershell) it compiles, while normally when there is an error in the browser it's mirrored here. Instead the console output is:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view extension in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://10.0.0.110:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

---

Here's a screen shot of the error message. This happens in `create-react-app` when you run the app using `npm start` from the project folder.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Eslint doesn't spit out type errors like that. can you take a screenshot of the error?

Comment: The error says to you that `chrome.storage` is undefined, which means that `"storage"` permission wasn't activated. Make sure to reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page after editing manifest.json and reload the tabs where the content scripts run.